# Django: get current domain name in setting.py

Tags: django, python-2.7

We can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in php to get current domain name.
Now I want to set ROOT_URLCONF in django's setting.py based on current domain name, what should I do about it?

Comment: You can use a different wsgi file based on the domain (assuming you are using wsgi) that pulls in different url conf files, but the cleanest solution is to use django-hosts as mentioned in my answer below. It basically handles this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [django-hosts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-hosts) to do this for you. It changes the url conf based on the domain name. It does this in the middleware layer.

It's very easy to set up.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. As I don't have permission to install package on the server, now my solution is to implement a function that matches all request and dispatch the request to other function based on the request_url.

Comment: Talk to the network administrator about setting up a virtualenv for your Django project. This will allow you to install packages just for your own website and nowhere else on the server. I'd say around 50% of Django's usefulness is that there are already libraries out there to handle most of your project; if you have to write everything yourself there's way less benefit.